# Align Navigation Drawer button in toolbar before title

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I want my button that opens navigation drawer to be displayed on the toolbar first in the left but I am unable to place it before the title. I tryed set `android:gravity="left"` but that does not seem to help. Can anyone help me with this?

[image: descriptive image]

Here is my toolbar xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:elevation="2dp"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_white_24dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was mistake to do it manually. I should use `ActionBarDrawerToggle`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following two methods:

First, in xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_white_24dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

Second, inside activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_child_swipe);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toobar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_white_24dp);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do something here
        }
    });
```